# Javascript Remove strings in beginning and end

Tags: javascript

base on the following string

```
...here..
..there...
.their.here.
```

How can i remove the `.` on the beginning and end of string like the trim  that removes all spaces, using javascript

the output should be

```
here
there
their.here
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

These are the reasons  why the RegEx for this task is `/(^\.+|\.+$)/mg`:

1. Inside `/()/` is where you write the pattern of the substring you want to find in the string:

   > `/(ol)/` This will find the substring `ol` in the string.

   `var x =  "colt".replace(/(ol)/, 'a');` will give you  `x == "cat"`;
2. The `^\.+|\.+$` in `/()/` is separated into 2 parts by the symbol `|` [means or]

   > `^\.+` and `\.+$`

   1. `^\.+` means to find as many `.` as possible at the start.

      > `^` means at the start; \ is to escape the character; adding  `+` behind a character means to match any string containing one or more that character
   2. `\.+$` means to find as many `.` as possible at the end.

      > `$` means at the end.
3. The `m` behind `/()/` is used to specify that if the string has newline or carriage return characters, the ^ and $ operators will now match against a newline boundary, instead of a string boundary.
4. The `g` behind `/()/` is used to perform a global match: so it find all matches rather than stopping after the first match.

To learn more about RegEx you can check out [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Well explained. Thanks.

Comment: @吖奇说-何魏奇ArchyWillHe, what if there are different string like `..--'some-name.'--` I just want to keep `some-name`, what change should be done. I have a case where string can have `-'.` at start or end number of times and i want to remove them

Answer (score 12):

Try to use the following regex

```
var text = '...here..\n..there...\n.their.here.';
var replaced =  text.replace(/(^\.+|\.+$)/mg, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QkUHJ/)

Use Regex `/(^\.+|\.+$)/mg`

- `^` represent at start
- `\.+` one or many full stops
- `$` represents at end

so:

```
var text = '...here..\n..there...\n.their.here.';
alert(text.replace(/(^\.+|\.+$)/mg, ''));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an non regular expression answer which utilizes String.prototype

```
String.prototype.strim = function(needle){
    var first_pos = 0;
    var last_pos = this.length-1;
    //find first non needle char position
    for(var i = 0; i<this.length;i++){
        if(this.charAt(i) !== needle){
            first_pos = (i == 0? 0:i);
            break;
        }
    }
    //find last non needle char position
    for(var i = this.length-1; i>0;i--){
        if(this.charAt(i) !== needle){
            last_pos = (i == this.length? this.length:i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return this.substring(first_pos,last_pos);
}
alert("...here..".strim('.'));
alert("..there...".strim('.'))
alert(".their.here.".strim('.'))
alert("hereagain..".strim('.'))
```

and see it working here : http://jsfiddle.net/cettox/VQPbp/

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more code-golfy, if not readable, non-regexp prototype extension:

```
String.prototype.strim = function(needle)   {
    var out = this;
    while (0 === out.indexOf(needle))
        out = out.substr(needle.length);
    while (out.length === out.lastIndexOf(needle) + needle.length)
        out = out.slice(0,out.length-needle.length);
    return out;
}

var spam = "this is a string that ends with thisthis";
alert("#" + spam.strim("this") + "#");
```

[Fiddle-ige](http://jsfiddle.net/jpcxrxxb/)

Answer (score 1):

Use RegEx with javaScript [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var res = s.replace(/(^\.+|\.+$)/mg, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace()` method to remove the unwanted string in a string

**Example:**

```
var str = '<pre>I'm big fan of Stackoverflow</pre>'

str.replace(/<pre>/g, '').replace(/<\/pre>/g, '')

console.log(str)
```

**output:**

Check rules on RULES blotter