# Trimming other characters than whitespace? (trim() for variable characters)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, trim

Is there an easy way to replace characters at the beginning and end of a string, but not in the middle? I need to trim off dashes. I know `trim()` exists, but it only trims whitespace.

Here's my use case:

Input:

```
university-education
-test
football-coach
wine-
```

Output:

```
university-education
test
football-coach
wine
```

Comment: Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1418083/490790) answer, but replace the `\s` with your symbol or make it an argument to the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Remove strings in beginning and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134860/javascript-remove-strings-in-beginning-and-end)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression.

```
^-*|-*$
```

**Explanation:**

`^` - start of the string 
`-*` matches a dash zero or more times 
`|` - or 
`-*` - matches a dash zero or more times 
`$` - end of the string

```js
function trimDashes(str){
  return str.replace(/^-*|-*$/g, '');
}
console.log(trimDashes('university-education'));
console.log(trimDashes('-test'));
console.log(trimDashes('football-coach'));
console.log(trimDashes('--wine----'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [the trim function of lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#trim). It does exactly what you want. It has a second parameter which allows you to pass the characters which should be trimmed. In your case you could use it like this:

`trim("-test", "-");`

Answer (score 0):

The 'trim' function here is inadequate. You can catch this gap using **'RegEx'** within the **'replace'** function.

```
   let myText = '-education';
   myText = myText.replace(/^\-+|\-+$/g, ''); // output: "education"
```

**Use in the array**

```
  let myTexts = [
    'university-education',
    '-test',
    'football-coach',
    'wine',
  ];

  myTexts = myTexts.map((text/*, index*/) => text.replace(/^\-+|\-+$/g, ''));
  /* output:
    (4)[
      "university-education",
      "test",
      "football-coach",
      "wine"
    ]
  */
```

```
/^\   beginning of the string, dashe, one or more times
|     or
\-+$  dashe, one or more times, end of the string
/g    'g' is for global search. Meaning it'll match all occurrences.
```

**Sample:**

```js
const removeDashes = (str) => str.replace(/^\-+|\-+$/g, '');

/* STRING EXAMPLE */
const removedDashesStr = removeDashes('-education');
console.log('removedDashesStr', removedDashesStr);
// ^^ output: "removedDashesStr education"

let myTextsArray = [
  'university-education',
  '-test',
  'football-coach',
  'wine',
];

/* ARRAY EXAMPLE */
myTextsArray = myTextsArray.map((text/*, index*/) => removeDashes(text));
console.log('myTextsArray', myTextsArray);
/*^ outpuut:
    myTextsArray [
      "university-education",
      "test",
      "football-coach",
      "wine"
    ]
*/
```